# How to assign a column to update by parameter?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, procedure

I want to update the inventory table, from a Sports uniforms, the sizes go from t0 to tXXXL, each one of the sizes is a column in the base data, so to update the stock of each size, I send the size, its quantity of purchase and the available stock.
I tried to create a trigger but it did not work, so I left it in a procedure that worked until I added this sentence.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ActualizarInventario`;
/*nombre=name of Team for example=Barcelona, Real Madrid, Lakers, Bulls etc.
cant=Quantity sold
talla=size.
stock=quantities available.
The columns are in VARCHAR*/

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ActualizarInventario`(IN 
nombre VARCHAR(40),IN cant VARCHAR(15),IN talla VARCHAR(15),IN stock 
VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Ventas_Uniforme VALUES(null,nombre,talla,cant,stock,NOW());
#This UPDATE it does not work
    UPDATE inventario AS inv SET talla =(CAST(stock AS INT)-CAST(cant AS 
INT))
WHERE inv.Nombre_Agregar=nombre;
END;

#This is the trigger that I try to make, but gave the same error.

UPDATE inventario AS inv SET new.Talla =(CAST(new.Stock AS INT)- 
CAST(new.Cantidad_Venta AS INT)) WHERE 
inv.Nombre_Agregar=new.Nombre_Uniforme
```

This throws me when I execute it.

> Procedure execution failed 
>   1054-Unknown column 'talla' in 'field list'

Comment: It looks like the talla field is not found. I would recommend you to run the equivalent sentence as a script in the MySQLAdmin

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.